# How to link a library by its exact name with gcc?

Tags: gcc, dynamic, linker, version

I am trying to generate a dynamic library target.so and to do this I need to link it dynamically to a library in which the version number appears at the end:

```
/path/to/library/lib_with_version_number.so.28
```

If the name of the library was only,

```
/path/to/library/lib_without_version_number.so
```

I can use

```
-L/path/to/library/ -l_without_version_number
```

(because I don't wan't to have the complete library path when I run ldd command).

My question is: How to do the same with the version number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an unavoidable need to link a library `libfoo.a` or `libbar.so.x.y.z` 
by exactly that name, rather than by following the usually wiser `-lfoo` convention, you can do so by using the `-l:` option instead, e.g.

```
-l:libfoo.a -l:libbar.so.x.y.z
```

This choice makes no difference to the behaviour of the `-L` option.

Comment: man ld.bfd will show you detail namespec.